# Creating Horizontal Title Bars using Spans

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a title thats centered within a div with two spans to the left and right of it. I managed to do so but there's two issues I just can't seem to think of a solution for.

1. The first involves vertically centering the two border spans with
   the middle span 'Title'.
2. The second is having the left border expand all to the left edge of the div and vice versa for the right (obviously the width of the spans would need to be changed from the original).

Using two hrs seemed like a good idea but would it probably involve too much hacking to do something so simple.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="title">
        <span class="border"></span>
        <span>Title</span>
        <span class="border"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {background: #eee; height: 100px; width: 100%;}
.title {margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;}
.title span:nth-child(2) {padding: 0 10px;}
.border {display: inline-block; width: 40px; background: #000; height: 1px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the lines before and after a word, than why not use pseudo elements? You will need single element, no `span` and no other element to achieve that effect.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KXQjL/)

I've made the below example from scratch, here, am using `:before` and `:after` pseudo to create virtual elements, and then am positioning them accordingly using `position: absolute;` which is set to `top: 50;` for vertical centering, and then am deducting the `width` of each pseudo element so that it doesn't overlap your word.

```
div {
   margin: 150px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}

div:before,
div:after {
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #f00;
}

div:before {
    left: -50px;
}

div:after {
    right: -50px;
}
```

---

As you commented, if you want the lines to expand fully from edge to edge.. than wrap the text in a `span` and make the changes as below in your CSS

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/KXQjL/8/) *(Expands 100%)*

```
<div><span>Hello</span></div>

div {
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
}

div span {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #f00;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how I'd like it to be but the only thing missing would be having the width of the left and right borders expand to the very edge of the parent div. So instead of having them be 50px wide it would essentially be the width of the space between the title itself and the parent div from both the left and right sides.

Comment: And originally I had the title div centered so the float you have in yours wouldn't work on mine.

Comment: @CarlEdwards you welcome :) and if the answer helped you than you can mark the answer as correct by clicking on the green tick besides my answer...